# How do I configure Logback to work on CloudBees

Tags: java, logging, cloud, logback, cloudbees

i am using **logback 1.0.0** and my configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


        <!--Daily rolling file appender -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>logs\motivosity_logback.log</File> <!-- make sure you have permissions on this file -->   
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <FileNamePattern>logs\logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</FileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

    </appender>


    <logger name="com.myapp">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.security.web.authentication">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

it works fine locally, but on cloudbees when i open my home page

i can't see any logs in the papertrailapp

i use the log as follows:

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyBean.class);

if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("INIT MyBean");
}
```

please advise why it's not working.

**UPDATE:**

- standard sysouts works fine: `System.out.println("INIT MyBean");`
- the class i want to log.debug at is in the package com.myapp.web.controllers and i have logger configured for **com.myapp** as follows:

but when i tried to sysout 
`System.out.println("######## DEBUG ENABLED: " + log.isDebugEnabled());` it prints false, it means that debug is not enabled for this class, which is very weird.

- another thing i tried `log.info("@PostConstruct MyBean");` and it worked fine, i tried to change the root logging level to be debug, but still only info is logged.

Comment: if you print to stdout - do you see that in papertrail?

Comment: @Michael Neale printing sysouts appears in papertrail.

Comment: @Michael Neale, another thing is when i print to stdout the value of `log.isDebugEnabled()` it prints false, any ideas why ?

Comment: @Michael Neale i added some updates, can you please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that my configuration is correct but it works only for info,error levels and debug level won't work.

Comment: odd - is that a logback bug? It should use the one appender you tell it to right?

Comment: @Michael Neale, i opened a support ticket for that and they are looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have it log to STDOUT or STDERR as appropriate: for example see:

[file and stdout appenders in logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140935/file-and-stdout-appenders-in-logback-xml)

(might be some better ones out there) - that ensures logs can go to any subsystem and work clustered and when apps migrate.

Comment: i already have STDOUT appender and have a reference to STDOUT appender in root log, so what i am missing ? can you please explain ?

Comment: do you mean i should add `<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />` inside each logger tag ?

Comment: FYI, my configuration matches cloudbees documentation: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Logging+with+Logback+and+Papertrail

Comment: You have a FILE section, which is not in the example configuration.

Comment: other stdout configuration are like the example, cloudbees support said that my configuration looks fine