# Replace log files with console logs in Apache NiFi Docker Container

Tags: docker, logging, apache-nifi, logback

I have a configured Docker environment and a Logging Driver which sends all logs to a logging server. For this to work with Apache NiFi all NiFi logs should be sent to StdOut and StdErr. By default NiFi Docker Container tails a nifi-app.log file, so all logs are routed to a Logging Driver.
There are two issues:

1. nifi-user.log messages are not tailed.
2. Log files are persisted in a separate volume. I don't want the logs to be stored anywhere except my central logging server.

There is one thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891147/apache-nifi-redirect-all-logs-to-stdout) but it does not resolve anything. The real problem is that even if to set all appender-refs to CONSOLE - all messages are intercepted by a org.apache.nifi.StdOut logger line by line. Setting log level of this logger to OFF turns off logging of any messages after "Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID" entry.

Is there a way to configure NiFi Docker image to avoid storing logs into files and route them directly to standard output?